# Is it possible that $A^k u + \beta A^k v \to 0$ with $\beta$ irrational?

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory

Suppose $A$ is an invertible integer square matrix and $u$, $v$ are nonzero vectors with integer entries.

Is it possible that

$$A^k u + \beta A^k v \to 0,$$

as $k \to \infty$, with $\beta$ irrational?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
A = \pmatrix{1& 1 \\ 0 & 1}\\
v = \pmatrix{1\\1}\\
u = Av = \pmatrix{2\\1}
$$

I believe that does the job, with $\beta$ being
$$
- \sqrt{5}$$
because this is one of the standard ways to generate the Fibonacci numbers, whose ratio tends to the golden ratio, which is irrational.